# Append Ajax Response Multiple Times Foreach Data Send

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, response

I have a list of users who waiting for pending payment. I Would like to created a mass payment to users who have pending.

I created ajax request for that

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#boxesAll").click(function () {
        $('input[name="boxes[]').prop('checked', this.checked);
            $submit_act.toggle( $submit_box.is(":checked") );
          $submit_act_paid.toggle( $submit_box.is(":checked") );
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            var numberChecked = $('input[name="boxes[]"]:checked').length;
            $('#count_item').html(numberChecked +' items');
            $('tr>td:first-child').addClass('bg-warning');
        } else {
            $('tr>td:first-child').removeClass('bg-warning');
        }
    });

    var id,resp,
      $submit_act = $(".btn-act").hide(),
      $count_item = $("#count_item").hide(),
      $submit_box = $('input[name="boxes[]"]').click(function() {
        $submit_act.toggle( $submit_box.is(":checked") );
        $count_item.toggle( $submit_box.is(":checked") );
    $('input[name="boxes[]"]').change(function() {
      $(this).parents('tr>td').toggleClass('bg-warning', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
    var numberChecked = $('input[name="boxes[]"]:checked').length;
    $('#count_item').html(numberChecked +' items selected');
    });

  $('.btn-act').click(function(){
    var btnid = jQuery(this).attr("id");
    var page = '<?=$page;?>';
    id = [];
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
      id[i] = $(this).val();
    });  
    if (confirm("Are you sure to "+btnid+" these items?")) {
     if(id.length === 0){
      alert("Please Select atleast one item(s).");
     }else{
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/<?=$settings['admin_dir'];?>?p=jquery&act='+btnid,
            data: {page:page,id:id},
            beforeSend: function() {
                $(".btn-act").attr("disabled", true);
                $(".btn-act").html('<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm align-middle" role="status" aria-hidden="true"><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></span> Please wait...');
            }
        }).done(function(t) {
            setTimeout(function() {  
                data = JSON.parse(t);
                if(data['result']=='success'){
                  var pages = "<?=$settings['admin_dir'];?>?p="+page;
                  if(data['type']=='payments'){
                    $(".btn-act").html('All Payment Paid');
                    $(".btn-act").attr("disabled", true);

                     for(var i=id.length; i>0; i--){
                      $("#action_response").append('<div id="resp">'+data['msg']+'</div>');
                     }
                      
                  }
                }else{
                    $(".btn-act").attr("disabled", false);
                    $(".btn-act").html('Failed to action');
                } 
            }, 3000);
            });
    }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

And the php to process it

```
if($_GET['act']=="payments"){
    if(isset($_POST["page"]) && isset($_POST["id"])){
      foreach($_POST["id"] as $id){
        $details = getDetails('user_payments','id',$id);
        $user = getDetails('users','id',$details["user_id"]);
      }
            $msg = array(
              "result" => 'success',
              "type" => 'payments',
              "msg" => 'Successfully paid to '.$user['username']
            );
        echo json_encode($msg);
    }
  }
```

All code is working, but I have a problem about the result. The result always return in same result.

For example I checked 4 items for payments, the result goes here

```
Successfully paid to user1
Successfully paid to user1
Successfully paid to user1
Successfully paid to user1
```

The result I want is append each user that I checked.

```
Successfully paid to user1
Successfully paid to user2
Successfully paid to user3
Successfully paid to user4
```

So we know which user have been paid successfully.
Let me know if someone can fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only return one message in your ajax response.
To get the multiple results you have to build the message in a loop

```
if($_GET['act']=="payments"){
  if(isset($_POST["page"]) && isset($_POST["id"])){
    $msg = [];
    foreach($_POST["id"] as $id){
      $details = getDetails('user_payments','id',$id);
      $user = getDetails('users','id',$details["user_id"]);
      $msg[] = 'Successfully paid to '.$user['username'];
    }
    $response = array(
      "result" => 'success',
      "type" => 'payments',
      "msg" => $msg
    );
    echo json_encode($response);
  }
}
```

.

```
for(var i=id.length; i>0; i--){
  $("#action_response").append('<div id="resp">'+data.msg[i]+'</div>');
}
```